# Vector of std::chrono::milliseconds

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++-chrono

I need to measure some times (Milliseconds) of my application over some iterations. To do that I want to use the std::chrono-Library. Now I want to create a vector of milliseconds, so I can store all my measured times in that vector. After that I would like to sort the vector to get the median.

But iam currently unable to create a vector. I dont know which type I should take to create it. Has somebody an idea, how this might work? I couldnt find any answers for my question.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
vector<chrono::milliseconds> times;

for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        //... the application to measure
        auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto elapsedtime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        times.push_back(elapsedtime);
}

std::sort(times.begin(), times.end());

std::cout << "Median: " << times.at(times.size()/2) << "(ms)" << endl;
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing? Compile errors? You need to give some more information.

Comment: Change your vector to std::vector<long> times and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector type is correct for storing `std::chrono::duration`. There should be no error in creating the vector.

There is however, a bug where you try to fill the vector here:

```
auto elapsedtime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
times.push_back(elapsedtime);
```

You set elapsed time to the value returned by `std::duration::count` which returns the internal tickcount of the duration. It's type is `std::duration::rep`. Just remove the count and it should work.

Comment: @user3531686 in general `.count()` should be avoided and `duration_cast`, like all casts, should be viewed with suspicion. In this case the cast is probably okay, though it might be better to change the vector type so that no conversion is necessary: `vector<chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration> times;` and then `times.push_back(end - start);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `elapsedtime` is not `chrono::milliseconds`, but `chrono::milliseconds::rep`. You can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<chrono::milliseconds> times;

  for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //... the application to measure
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedtime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    times.push_back(chrono::milliseconds(elapsedtime));
  }

  std::sort(times.begin(), times.end());

  std::cout << "Median: " << times.at(times.size()/2).count() << "(ms)" << endl;
}
```

Or this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<chrono::milliseconds::rep> times;

  for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //... the application to measure
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedtime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    times.push_back(elapsedtime);
  }

  std::sort(times.begin(), times.end());

  std::cout << "Median: " << times.at(times.size()/2) << "(ms)" << endl;
}
```

Or even

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<chrono::milliseconds> times;

  for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //... the application to measure
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedtime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    times.push_back(elapsedtime);
  }

  std::sort(times.begin(), times.end());

  std::cout << "Median: " << times.at(times.size()/2).count() << "(ms)" << endl;
}
```

([live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c40108a61f088af1))

Comment: Also thanks to you for the fast answer! I know use the last option and it works perfectly.

Comment: Or: `vector<chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration> times;` and `times.push_back(end - start);`. I would strongly recommend against using `vector<chrono::milliseconds::rep>`. The first option is dangerously redundant and creates an opportunity for this mistake: `times.push_back(chrono::microseconds(elapsedtime));`, however I'd still prefer that over the second option.